# how do you style (big) short-circuit assignment in javascripts?

Tags: javascript, eslint, airbnb-js-styleguide

imagine that you have this line:

```js
var result = content['aPossbileValue'] || $el.data('root-path') + content.type +  '/something/' + content.slug;
```

The line length is too long, so i wonder how can i improve this?

Possible options:

```js
var result = content['aPossbileValue'] 
  || $el.data('root-path') + content.type + '/something/' + content.slug;
```

```js
var result = content['aPossbileValue'] ||
             $el.data('root-path') + content.type + '/something/' + content.slug;
```

```js
var result = content['aPossbileValue'] 
             || $el.data('root-path') + content.type + '/something/' + content.slug
```

Or maybe it's considered a bad practice!

let me know your opinion ^^!

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to reduce the length of the line, one possibility is to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on the `content` object to first get the related properties. On a second step, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to generate the `default` value assigned to result in case `aPossibleValue` results on a `falsy` value. Something like this:

```
let {aPossibleValue, type, slug} = content;
var result = aPossibleValue || $el.data('root-path') + `${type}/something/${slug}`;
```

But you should note, these are `ES6` features, not supported on some browsers and/or versions. So, always check the browser compatibility section. In the case you can't have access this luxury, I will go with something like this:

```
let val = content.aPossibleValue, type = content.type, slug = content.slug;
var result = val | $el.data('root-path') + type + '/something/' + slug;
```

Comment: i really like your idea! but i'm using es5 :(

Comment: @edudepetris you can always save object's data into variables with a shorter name description.

Answer (score 0):

Using variables with descriptive name are more readable than long and complex lines. In your case, this would be better:

```
var customPath = $el.data('root-path') + type + '/something/' + slug;
var result = content['aPossibleValue'] || customPath;
```